# How to make Source Safe read only?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Recently we migrated from VSS to SVN. But I don't want VSS removed totally, instead I want everyone can access it read only? Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VSS admin you can set each user to be read-only.

Comment: Yes I know it, but is there any better way? because we have 15 users!

Comment: By the time you read this, you could be done.  15 users is nothing.